# Creating Matrix Instance Variable from other Matrix Variable in Class Declaration Swift

Tags: swift, matrix

I'm programming in Swift and trying to create a map object that contains all the places in a world I am trying to build. First, I instantiated all the different location objects that I will have in my map. I need to index them in some sort of data structure, but when I try to create another instance variable, a matrix, an array of arrays using the instantiated locations, the Swift compiler gives me an error. Is there any way to get around this, or am I just no allowed to use other instance variables to create new ones? I am sort of new to OOP, so if this is a stupid question, I apologize. As alway, many thanks.

```
class Map: NSObject {
    //Instantiate all the places on your map by instantiating locations
    let seaofFrigado = Location(name: "seaofFrigado")
    let shippensport = Location(name: "Shippensport")
    let drivensFarms = Location(name: "Driven's Farms")
    let deadmansRift = Location(name: "Deadman's Rift")
    let siccumDesert = Location(name: "Siccum Desert")
    let shalkensSands = Location(name: "Shalken's Sands")
    let yellowForest = Location(name: "Yellow Forrest")
    let arxRei = Location(name: "Arx Rei")
    let urbsrei = Location(name: "Urbsrei")
    let kaldersCavern = Location(name: "Kalder's Cavern")
    let mountRugnor = Location(name: "Mount Rugnor")
    let havenValley = Location(name: "Haven Valley")
    let tyvanyasOrchard = Location(name: "Tyvanya's Orchard")
    let aethalwaldsFarm = Location(name: "Aethelwald's Farm")
    let magnoppidumNorth = Location(name: "Magnoppidum North")
    let ancientRuins = Location(name: "Ancient Ruins")
    let mountVeldunr = Location(name: "Mount Veldunr")
    let nomadsPass = Location(name: "Nomad's Pass")
    let magnoppidumWest = Location(name: "Magnoppidum West")
    let magnoppidumCenter = Location(name: "Magnoppidum Center")


    let map: [[Location]] = [[seaofFrigado, shippensport, drivensFarms, deadmansRift, siccumDesert], [shalkensSands, yellowForest, arxRei, urbsrei, kaldersCavern], [mountRugnor, havenValley, tyvanyasOrchard, aethalwaldsFarm, magnoppidumNorth], [ancientRuins, mountVeldunr, nomadsPass, magnoppidumWest, magnoppidumCenter]]
```

Answer (score 0):

All your variables are constants. Also you probably don't need to inherit from NSObject unless you are interfacing with Obj-C code.

Try a format like this:

```
class Map {
  var map: [[Location]]

  init() {
    //Instantiate all the places on your map by instantiating locations
    let seaofFrigado = Location(name: "seaofFrigado")
    let shippensport = Location(name: "Shippensport")
    let drivensFarms = Location(name: "Driven's Farms")
    let deadmansRift = Location(name: "Deadman's Rift")
    let siccumDesert = Location(name: "Siccum Desert")
    let shalkensSands = Location(name: "Shalken's Sands")
    let yellowForest = Location(name: "Yellow Forrest")
    let arxRei = Location(name: "Arx Rei")
    let urbsrei = Location(name: "Urbsrei")
    let kaldersCavern = Location(name: "Kalder's Cavern")
    let mountRugnor = Location(name: "Mount Rugnor")
    let havenValley = Location(name: "Haven Valley")
    let tyvanyasOrchard = Location(name: "Tyvanya's Orchard")
    let aethalwaldsFarm = Location(name: "Aethelwald's Farm")
    let magnoppidumNorth = Location(name: "Magnoppidum North")
    let ancientRuins = Location(name: "Ancient Ruins")
    let mountVeldunr = Location(name: "Mount Veldunr")
    let nomadsPass = Location(name: "Nomad's Pass")
    let magnoppidumWest = Location(name: "Magnoppidum West")
    let magnoppidumCenter = Location(name: "Magnoppidum Center")

    map = [[seaofFrigado, shippensport, drivensFarms, deadmansRift, siccumDesert], [shalkensSands, yellowForest, arxRei, urbsrei, kaldersCavern], [mountRugnor, havenValley, tyvanyasOrchard, aethalwaldsFarm, magnoppidumNorth], [ancientRuins, mountVeldunr, nomadsPass, magnoppidumWest, magnoppidumCenter]]
  }
}

var map1 = Map()
var map2 = Map()
```

This should get the functionality that you are looking for

Comment: would i be able to reference map1.map[x][y]?

Comment: Yep that's how it would work. Were you wanting to do something different? You could create an instance function on Map so you could use: map1.getLocation(x,y)

Comment: so what is map and why don't you need to declare let or var?